# Finding a specific Mysql user whose name starts with a specific letter?

Tags: mysql

Imagine, my MySQL db contains 1000 users and I want to find only one specific user whose name starts with a letter`m`(Maybe all users whose names start with letter `m`). How can I do that.

Below is the command that finds all the users on mysql. How can I modify that to find only a specific user whose name starts with a letter `m`

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`LIKE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) and `%` wildcard:

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.`user` WHERE name LIKE 'm%';
```

You may need to add `COLLATE UTF8_GENERAL_CI` to make it case insensitive.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you.